# can't display an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I put an image in both folder: 
/Views/Home/chart02.jpg and /Content/chart02.jpg

In the view file index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<p>
To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.

    <img src="<%= @Url.Content("~/Content/chart02.jpg") %>" />  
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/chart02.jpg") %>" />    
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~")%>/Content/chart02.jpg"/>
    <%= Url.Content("~/Home/chart02.jpg") %>
</p>
```

But none of them works.
In the View Page Source:

```
<p>
To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.

    <img src="<%= /Content/chart02.jpg %>" />    
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/chart02.jpg") %>" />   
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~")%>/Content/chart02.jpg"/>
    <%= Url.Content("~/Home/chart02.jpg") %>
</p>
```

Do I miss something somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mix of Razor and WebForms. Your markup should looks like:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/chart02.jpg")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited now that you're post is cleaned up and your code is showing properly:

In each one of your image tags, you have a slight error. If you're using MVC 3 and Razor, you don't use <%= %> anymore. Just prefix the code with @.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/chart02.jpg")">
```

or, depending on your version of MVC, you can skip the [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
<img src="~/Content/chart02.jpg">
```